Deploy an application on kubernetes but the pods are always in CrashLoopBackOff state
I'm trying to deploy an application with a NodePort Service on Kubernets cluster, but the deployment doesn't work, and the pods are in a CrashLoopBackOff state with this logs:

panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "go"
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
/server/main.go:15 +0x1f4

This is the manifest of the app :
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-angular-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: go-angular-app
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: go-angular-app
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: go-angular-app
        image: xxxxx
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: "go"
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            value: "root"
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: "go"
          - name: POSTGRES_HOST
            value: "students-db-svc"

And this is the manifest of the service of the app :
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: go-angular-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: go-angular-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30081

And this is the manifest of the Postgress deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: students-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: students-db
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: students-db
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:11.5
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: "go"
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            value: "root"
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: "go"

and this is the db service manifest :
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: students-db-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: students-db
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432

I tried changing the environment variables and nothing has changed the pods are always on that state and they are supposed to be in RUNNING state What to do ? and thank you.

What is the output of kubectl describe pod <POD-NAME>? You can find out the name of the pod with the command kubectl get pods in the Namespace of the Deployment.

The output of decribe pod is :
Warning BackOff
4m44s (x5057 over 18h) kubelet Back-off restarting failed container go-angular-app in pod go-angul ar-app-6bf54d4db9-jrc5x_default(52d4be18-d43d-4c19-b1f5-db914bdaed1b)

Isn't there more information? This just tells us what we already know: The pod has a problem and will be restarted. The problem is likely to remain, so we need information about the reason, there may be messages like "failed to get container image" or "readiness probe failed", do you see anything like that in the output? The output must be more than what you put in the comment…

Sadly there is no other information in the output of describe

And what about the output of kubectl describe deploy <DEPLOYMENT-NAME>?

It looks like you're getting a clear error message from your application about the database credentials.  What code establishes the database connection?  (Are you correctly using the environment variables from the Deployment spec?)

@DavidMaze Exactly, I guess they are correct. I've just published the manifests to ensure that I'm specifying it right because I had some doubts.

refer to this stack link it might be helpful,
Also check the container logs for more information
